# open file by file name else display message PHP

Tags: php, fopen

I ask the user to enter a filename, if the file is present, the file opens, if not user, gets an error message "File Not Found!"

I have it working to the point where i can view contents of the file. I can't get it to display error if file is not found.

```
<form name"form4" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Enter File Name: <input type="text" name="fileName"><br><br>
<input name="name" type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
$myfile = fopen("files/document.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("files/document.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
 }
 ?>
```

Looking over the code, I think i need to $myfile to be equal to "fileName", it needs a value to eval against.

```
 $filename = $_POST["fileName"]? am i grasping at straws?
```

Comment: put your PHP inside an `isset()` and using your submit button's name attribute. check folder/file permissions also.

Comment: Hi Fred, I fixed the typo. I still can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `file_exists` before you try to open a file which might not exists.
It's always better to prevent errors than handle errors.

```
$file = "files/document.txt";
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $myfile = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($myfile) {
        echo fread($myfile,filesize("files/document.txt"));
        fclose($myfile);
    }
} else {
    echo "Unable to open file!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to set your isset code to: (isset($_POST['fileName']))
   2.You need to set a variable under your isset code that takes the value of your textbox like so: $file2 = ($_POST['fileName']);
2. Then you need to enclose your fopen code within an if...else statement:

if ($file2 == "document.txt") {.......}